# Curious about stuff in the usr/bin

Tags: history

I was looking through usr/bin and was looking at the names of directories. There are a few I cannot find anything about online, and cannot get to execute (or don't know the arguments).

moo-outdated
moo-outdated5.18
moose-outdated
moose-outdated5.18
moose-outdated5.30

If anyone knows about these, it would be cool to learn about!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't know what they are either except that they are files not directories.  But three things to try:

1. Terminal command `man moose`, etc. In this case it does not help.
2. Terminal command `cat /usr/bin/moose-outdated`.
   This shows it is a perl module. Perl is still distributed with macOS and you will have little use for it unless you are a developer.
3. Web search (choose your favourite search engine) for `+"moose-outdated" macOS`. From that I discovered [Moose at CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) which describes Moose as "A postmodern object system for Perl 5".

There you have it.

Comment: Correct. Moose is an object system for Perl 5 inspired by the object system of the Raku programming language (i.e. the programming language formerly known as Perl 6).

Comment: [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) is a similar system, inspired by Moose, but simpler and faster to load.  Perl 5.18 was superseded in May 2014.